# autoset Bearing of my mapsFragment based on SmartphoneSensor

Tags: google-maps, kotlin

I need to implement in my Android App this function (see image).

[image]

I want that the Camera (bearing I think) follow smartphone direction. You can use Google maps to better understand.

Can you help me, please? 
I use Kotlin.

UPDATE: Now i use GPS.bearing and work!! But now i want use smartphonsensor as googlemaps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Such customization is not available at Google Maps SDK.

Comment: Nothing even near
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory